# Is there a python library equivalent to php's curl_getinfo?

Tags: php, python, http, curl

PHP's `curl_getinfo` returns detailed breakdown about request time (see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) for more details). Is there a python library that can do the same thing?

Comment: @downvoter, does this question break any community rules? Can you please leave a comment explaining the downvote? Thanks.

Comment: upvote for restore justice (no reason for the downvote).

Comment: This could be read as a request for off-site resources, which is discouraged here, which may be why it was down voted and 3 people have voted to close it. I personally voted to leave it open, because I feel that, as phrased, this isn't a straight up request for a library, but that it'd be acceptable to post, IE, an answer that uses nothing more than the built in `urllib` module to replicate that php function. In case you don't already have this bookmarked OP, the best reference for Python is: https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[(py)curl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) has [getinfo](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/curlobject.html#pycurl.Curl.getinfo)

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO

curl = pycurl.Curl()
buff = cStringIO.StringIO()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://example.org')
curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, buff.write)
curl.perform()

print "status code: %s" % curl.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
```

Comment: I am happy to have helped you